# Wierd behaviour in testing angular-ui-router $urlRouterProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test the default redirect for my angularjs application based on angular ui router, No matter what I did, the otherwise config was ignored, I tried to forcefully call the update method of urlRouter, To achieve this I injected $urlRouter in my test. voila original code started working.

https://gist.github.com/himangshuj/8142045

This is the gist of my change. Revision 4 is the thing that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using $urlRouterProvider without $stateProvider, you have to inject $urlRouter in order for it to be initialized and properly hook into $location..

answered on github, it seems this is expected behavior

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/718#issuecomment-31246720